# Nginx - fails with multipart request with custom boundary having (CRLF)

Tags: nginx, mime-types, content-type, mime

Nginx - fails with multipart request with custom boundary having (CRLF),while from RFC it's a perfectly valid payload.
Example payload. 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
    boundary=------%^TestBoundary^%------
with multiple files.

At first the special characters on the header was causing the boundary to be skipped from passing to the backend, added ignore_invalid_headers off. Now I see the content-type header passed to the backend but with a notorious ":" added to it.

multipart/form-data;    boundary=------%^TestBoundary^%------**:**

Any clue what's causing this ? How do i fix it on the nginx before passing to the backend ?

Comment: Note there is a \r\n\t between Content-Type: multipart/form-data; and boundary=... which is causing the issue otherwise it works fine. But it's perfectly fine as pre the RFC (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is is a known bug that is most likely your problem where the "boundary" part is appended to the Content-Type string using CRLF plus a TAB:
https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?29,192093,192102#msg-192102

If you cannot fix this in your code then you would need to use HAProxy or something similar to fix this by replacing the CRLF + TAB with LWS (see the "Important note" at the bottom of section 1.2.2 in this https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.7/doc/configuration.txt)